# Sort packages by size one-liner as function

Tags: bash, command, function

While surfing web I've discovered nice one-liner that suits my needs well

```
expac -s "%-30n %m" | sort -hk 2 | awk '{print $1, $2/1024/1024}' | column -t|
```

However all the functional needed I got used to wrap in functions and there is problem in making function from this one-liner.

So I tried to insert this into my `.bashrc` file:

```
size()
{
    expac -s "%-30n %m" | sort -hk 2 | awk '{print $1, $2/1024/1024}' | column -t
}
```

and got this error:

```
[user@srv ~]$ size: a.out: No such file
```

So my question is: what's wrong about this function and how to fix it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the way you ran the function. Also specify whether you tried it in  new shell (or at least ran `source ~/.bashrc`). The error you get suggests that, as Yeti explained in their answer, you're running `/usr/bin/size` instead of your function.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ which size
/usr/bin/size
```

The shell executes the binary named `size` instead of your function.

Just name your function differently.

Apart from confusion now, you might need the original `size` someday.

Comment: No, user defined function is used first.

Comment: @cuonglm yes but the specific error is exactly what you'd expect from `/usr/bin/size`. I'm guessing the OP did not source `.bashrc` after editing it.